# Fetch Post not working in redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, cors, fetch-api, redux-saga

I have the following code by using redux-saga to send a post request:

```
import {put, call, fork, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
const url = 'xxx/api/posts';


function* addPost(data) {
    try{
        const response = yield fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        const id = yield response.json().id;
        yield put({type: types.ADD_POST, payload: {id, title, content }});
    }catch(e) {
        yield put({type: types.ERROR, payload: e});
    }
}
```

But an ajax is sent with the 'OPTION' method, what's wrong with my code? Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

The server you’re sending the request to must be configured to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header whose value contains `Content-Type`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests explains what’s happening here. Your request triggers your browser to send a CORS “preflight”.

The specific reason the browser does the preflight in this case is that the request includes a `Content-Type: application/json` request header. The CORS protocol requires that if a cross-origin request includes a `Content-Type` request header with a value other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
`multipart/form-data`,
`text/plain`, the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request and then checks the response to that to see if the response includes  an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header whose value contains `Content-Type`.

If the browser finds that the response includes a response header that includes that value, then the browser will then proceed to send that actual `POST` request you’re trying to make with your code. But if the browser instead finds that the response doesn’t include that header, or that the header doesn’t contain `Content-Type`, then the browser will stop right there and not send the `POST`.